# How can I import a module named [userinput] in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, try-catch

I'm trying to take the user's input, and see if there's a module named whatever they input. If there is, I then want that module to be imported, and to call a function within it of the same name. I know there are more simple ways of doing this, but I wanted to try and make it super compact.

This was my idea:

```
userinput = str.lower(input(prompt))
try:
    import (userinput) as _(userinput)
    _(userinput).(userinput)
except:
    print("Module not found")
```

If it couldn't find a module with the name given, it would simply trip the exception and continue.

My problem is being able to import a module from the string given from the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
userinput = str.lower(input(prompt))
try:
    exec("import %s as _(userinput)"%(userinput))
    #_(userinput).(userinput)  ???????
except:
    print("Module not found")
```

The exec() part works, but I'm not sure what you want to do with the _(userinput).(userinput)

Comment: If you don't care if a user types `os;os.remove('~')#` this would work.

Comment: Using `exec("{}. _{}" .format(userinput,userinput))` will probably work, just not recognizing the module I wish to import.

Comment: What do you mean by "recognizing the module"?

Comment: So if I run that and input the name of the module, it trips the exception instead of importing and running the module.

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__import__` function.

```
userinput = input("Enter name of module to import: ")
module = __import__(userinput)
```